# Formula to pull selection based on row and column cross-reference

Tags: drop-down-menu, formula, calculation, cross-reference

Using a drop-down selections, one pulls from Row, one pulls from column and then based on those selections the cell would show the cross-reference.

Example: Take a Multiplication Table concept
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
2   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
3   3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36
4   4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
5   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
6   6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
7   7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84
8   8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96
9   9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99  108
10  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 110 120
11  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  110 121 132
12  12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108 120 132 144

In cell 'A1', you have drop-down list that chooses from the row and you select '5'.
In cell 'B1', you have drop-down list that chooses from the column and you select '5'.
In cell 'C1', it shows you the cross-reference of '25'.

What formula would I use in 'C1' to show the cross-reference result based on the drop-down selections?

Comment: To better understand you question: Could you format you table?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Why is the simple thing `=A1*B1` not working? 
Normally it doesn't matter if it is a user enter value or a value from a drop down